# Why React Native functions in Components don't have "function" keyword?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In javascript functions are declared as `function myFuncName() {}`, but React/React Native functions omits the keyword. Is this a ES6, JSX, or React specific?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of ES6.

See more at https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-classes