# javascript usual function declaration is not working inside the React Component

Tags: javascript, react-native

am a newbie for javascript and react.Can anyone tell me what is the problem when am writing usual function declaration inside the class Component.It's showing error unexpected token.construtor,method,prop accessor .... is requried.

[image: on the function keyword there is a warning]

Comment: Please [include code (and errors) as text, not as an image of text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

Omit the 'function' reserved word. You don't need it inside of class

Answer (score 0):

Replace function hello(params){} to

hello(params){}

or

hello = (params) => {}

Comment: yes i know this , but y can't we write usual function declaration inside a class any reasons for that

Comment: Hi Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159207/why-react-native-functions-in-components-dont-have-function-keyword